# What are the values iside hevc_nvenc presets?

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia-graphics-card, h.265

I'm trying to setup `hevc_nvenc` encoder in `ffmpeg` to get best result for further postponing. Unfortunately documentation I've found is very terrible. I want to find out **what are the values under the presets** (slow, lossless, fast, etc...) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_nvenc` to get the list of presets.

The choices are

```
-preset            <int>        E..V..... Set the encoding preset (from 0 to 11) (default medium)
     default                      E..V.....
     slow                         E..V..... hq 2 passes
     medium                       E..V..... hq 1 pass
     fast                         E..V..... hp 1 pass
     hp                           E..V.....
     hq                           E..V.....
     bd                           E..V.....
     ll                           E..V..... low latency
     llhq                         E..V..... low latency hq
     llhp                         E..V..... low latency hp
     lossless                     E..V..... lossless
     losslesshp                   E..V..... lossless hp
```

To know how individual parameters are affected by each preset, you'll need to call `nvEncGetEncodePresetConfig()` for which you need access to the NvEnc SDK.

Comment: Those are possible presses, but the question is what options and values are preseted by them.

Comment: I can't find a current published list. You'll need to call `nvEncGetEncodePresetConfig()` if you have access to the NvEnc SDK. ffmpeg does not parse and log this data at present.

Comment: can you update your response with that?